# Webdev failed with an unexpected exception (Dart SDK 2.0.0-dev.69.1)

Tags: dart, angular-dart

1. I have updated **Dart SDK** to `2.0.0-dev.69.1` version.
2. Also, I hace updated my *pubspec.yaml* file to this:

   ```
   environment:
       sdk: '>=2.0.0-dev.69.1 <2.0.0'

   dependencies:
       sass_builder: ^2.1.1
       angular: ^5.0.0-beta+2
       angular_components: ^0.9.0-beta
       angular_forms: ^2.0.0-beta+2
       angular_router: ^2.0.0-alpha+17
       js: ^0.6.1+1
       path: ^1.6.2

   dev_dependencies:
       angular_test: ^2.0.0-beta+2
       build_runner: ^0.9.2
       build_test: ^0.10.3+1
       build_web_compilers: ^0.4.1
       test: ^1.3.0
   ```
3. I run the command `pub global activate webdev`.

⚠ After these steps, I tried to run `webdev serve` command. I receive this error message:

```
webdev failed with an unexpected exception.
Unable to spawn isolate: file:///C:/Users/marco/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/analyzer-0.32.3/lib/src/dart/analysis/library_context.dart:96:34: Error: Can't return a value from a void function.
        return appendLibraryFiles(targetLibrary);
                                 ^
```

❔ Did you also find the same problem? How can I solve this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an issue with SDK 2.0.0-dev.69.1 -- see [this announcement](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/d/msg/misc/6eYEC2T5U9Y/bftZbBICCAAJ). I'm not sure if it is related, but you might need to wait for the next release of the SDK, or downgrade to 2.0.0-dev.69.0.

Comment: AngularDart still has a bug, I think. With `Dart SDK 2.0.0-dev.69.2` this is an error. `webdev failed with an unexpected exception. Unable to spawn isolate: file:///C:/Users/marco/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/build_web_compilers-0.4.1/lib/builders.dart:24:36: Error: Method not found: 'KernelBuilder'.
Builder ddcKernelBuilder(_) => new KernelBuilder(
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^
file:///C:/Users/marco/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/build_web_compilers-0.4.1/lib/builders.dart:25:5: Error: No named parameter with the name 'summaryOnly'`